# how to connect to rds private instance after ssh into bastion host

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

how can i connect rds private instance after haved ssh into bastion host.

I have created a VPC with the following config:

- A Bastion (EC2 instance) in a public subnet
- Two private subnets, which are connected to AWS RDS...

I was able to SSH into the Bastion, but i am unable to access the postgres like i would do locally with `psql postgres`.

I tried to do the steps from here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/ but i cant copy a private key, its too long and does not work

also i tried `psql --host=yyy.xxx.us-east-z.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=someusername --password --dbname=postgres`, which is how someone would connect via psql and the error message i receive in the terminal is `The program 'psql' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing...` (i shouldnt have to install psql, i suppose since with a public RDS i dont install it..., no?)

The only thing working at the moment is that i am able to `telnet RDS Endpoint:5432` and it work

I am using terraform so my security groups are:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds" {
  name   = "rds"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
   protocol         = "tcp"
   from_port        = 5432
   to_port          = 5432
   cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Any help would be helpful

Comment: "but its not working"  - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors? What are your security groups?

Comment: @Marcin sorry i just updated the post. thanks

Comment: Your post is confusing. First you had issue about dns error, now about missing psql? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @Marcin i realized that i was no longer inside the bastion, so i sshed back into it..i just want to connect to the RDS private instance from the bastion ec2 instance that i am currently inside of

Comment: You have to install psql. Did you do that?

Comment: @Marcin i can really beat myself, i thought there was no need to but its actually the solution, i am inside RDS now thanks

Comment: "but i cant copy a private key, its too long "  The instructions you linked to don't say anything about copying a private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **missing** `psql` on the bastion. It was solved by installing it.